# Remove extra decimal place in float datatype on symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have in my database the ff. float:

```
1
1.5
1.7
2
```

I need to keep this as is in the program, but somehow symfony automatically convert these to ff by default:

```
1.00
1.50
1.70
2.00
```

My schema:

```
chapterno:
  type: float(4)
  fixed: false
  unsigned: true
  primary: false
  notnull: true
  autoincrement: false
```

xdebug trace before and after the function call:

```
0.4769   12560704                                 -> sfOutputEscaperIteratorDecorator->__construct() G:\Duc\xampp\htdocs\msym\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\escaper\sfOutputEscaper.class.php:125
0.4770   12560704                                   -> sfOutputEscaper->__construct() G:\Duc\xampp\htdocs\msym\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\escaper\sfOutputEscaperIteratorDecorator.class.php:49
0.4770   12560944                                   -> IteratorIterator->__construct() G:\Duc\xampp\htdocs\msym\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\escaper\sfOutputEscaperIteratorDecorator.class.php:51
0.4771   12560944                                     -> Doctrine_Record->getIterator() G:\Duc\xampp\htdocs\msym\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrine\Record.php:0
0.4771   12561384                                       -> Doctrine_Record_Iterator->__construct() G:\Duc\xampp\htdocs\msym\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrine\Record.php:2166
0.4771   12561384                                         -> Doctrine_Record->getData() G:\Duc\xampp\htdocs\msym\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrine\Record\Iterator.php:53
0.4771   12561416                                         -> ArrayIterator->__construct() G:\Duc\xampp\htdocs\msym\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrine\Record\Iterator.php:53
0.4771   12562056                             -> sfOutputEscaperIteratorDecorator->key() G:\Duc\xampp\htdocs\msym\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\escaper\sfOutputEscaperIteratorDecorator.class.php:0
0.4772   12562088                               -> IteratorIterator->key() G:\Duc\xampp\htdocs\msym\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\escaper\sfOutputEscaperIteratorDecorator.class.php:81
0.4772   12560272                             -> sfOutputEscaperIteratorDecorator->getChapterno() G:\Duc\xampp\htdocs\msym\apps\frontend\modules\book\templates\indexSuccess.php:5
0.4772   12560424                               -> sfOutputEscaperObjectDecorator->__call() G:\Duc\xampp\htdocs\msym\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\escaper\sfOutputEscaperObjectDecorator.class.php:0
0.4772   12560456                                 -> count() G:\Duc\xampp\htdocs\msym\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\escaper\sfOutputEscaperObjectDecorator.class.php:47
0.4772   12560672                                 -> call_user_func_array() G:\Duc\xampp\htdocs\msym\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\escaper\sfOutputEscaperObjectDecorator.class.php:64
0.4773   12561072                                   -> sfDoctrineRecord->__call() G:\Duc\xampp\htdocs\msym\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\record\sfDoctrineRecord.class.php:0
0.4773   12561200                                     -> substr()
```

I don't need this kind of functionality, how can i disable this?

Comment: $c->getChapterno();-> this is my code

Comment: What does your database schema look like? Do you use a FLOAT column? Or DECIMAL perhaps?

Comment: I've added the Schema on my post. :)

Comment: What is the type of the data you are displaying (use `var_dump()`) to determine whether it is string or float)?

Comment: it's string. how can i prevent symfony auto convert to string?

Comment: @DucDigital: could you do step by step debugging with xdebug, or a trace with `xdebug_trace_start()` and `xdebug_trace_stop()` before and after your `echo`, so that we can see which methods are called?

Comment: @greg0ire : I just update the xdebug on my post.

Comment: @DucDigital: I think the end of the trace is lacking, it stops on `substr()`

Comment: yes, that's where I start to substr to remove 0s.

Comment: @DucDigital let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1362/discussion-between-greg0ire-and-ducdigital)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me. Casting to float solves it. Just do this:

```
echo (float) $chapter->getChapterNo();
```

You may also override `getChapterNo()` to do this for you (use _get in your override to avoid infinite loops with `__call()`.

**UPDATE**
I reported this [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DC-1017), so you can subscribe if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need this type in your schema:

```
chapterno: { type: decimal, size: 2, scale: 1 }
```

To remove .0 from the number you can use this php code:

```
preg_match("/([0-9](\.[1-9]))|[0-9]/", $chapterno, $match);
```

Of course $match[0] is the needed result.

Comment: the output of this will be 1.0 and 1.5.

Comment: In my form I get this result.

Comment: is there anyway to just return the plain result without padding .0? i currently using trim to remove unnecessary part, but it's not program wide.

Comment: I mean regex can do this work. The pattern ([0-9](\.[1-9]))|[0-9] removes .0